# Alternate method of iterating than os.walk

Tags: python, performance, recursion, file-system

Recently, I became tired of how slowly `os.walk` seems to run (really, it should be called `os.crawl`), and made something recursive which moves much faster.  I was using it to take directories I wanted and add them to an array, but this time I need to add all files to an array that aren't in an 'exclude array.' Does anyone have any advice?

```
import os

exclude_folders = ['excludefolder1', 'excludefolder2']
product_path_names = ['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3']
# This function replaces the os.walk, it is faster and stops scanning subdirectories
# when it find a good folder name.
def findDir(path):
    for directory in os.listdir(path):
     # If it's a folder that we want to scan, go for it.
        if(os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, directory))):
            # If folder is a product name, add it.
            if(directory.lower() in product_path_names):
                print os.path.join(path, directory)
                product_dirs.append(os.path.join(path, directory))
                with open(event_log_path, "a") as log:        
                    log.write(os.path.join(path, directory) + "\n")
                break
            # If folder is not a product name, scan it.
            else:
                #print os.path.join(path, directory)
                if(directory.lower() not in exclude_folders):
                    findDir(os.path.join(path, directory))
```

Comment: This is working code?

Comment: yes, you just need to import os

Comment: Working code that you'd like comments on for improvement goes to Code Review.SE, I'll send it there now.

Comment: I assume the indentation bug in the `log.write` line arose from the conversion to SE Markdown; if not, there was an indentation bug.

Comment: It was from the conversion, thanks for catching it though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Style

- According to PEP 8, functions should be named using `lower_case()`.
- Python code typically doesn't have parentheses around `if` conditions.
- You call `os.path.join()` everywhere.  It would be worthwhile to assign the joined path to a variable.

### Error handling

If any operation fails (for example, if you do not have permission to list some directory), then the whole search aborts with an exception.

### Modularity and reusability

The inclusion and exclusion lists should be parameters rather than globals.

By the Single Responsibility Principle, a function should do just one thing.  The function you have written not only finds the directories that have the desired names, it also prints their path to `sys.stdout`, appends the results to a list, and logs the occurrence.

By making the function into a generator, you would give the caller the flexibility to do whatever it wants with the results.  The caller can even have the option to terminate early after the first result.  `find_dirs()` would then become a more generically useful function.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys

def find_dirs(root_dir, names, exclude_folders=[]):
    try:
        for entry in os.listdir(root_dir):
            entry_path = os.path.join(root_dir, entry)
            entry_lowercase = entry.lower()
            if os.path.isdir(entry_path):
                if entry_lowercase in names:
                    yield entry_path
                elif entry_lowercase not in exclude_folders:
                    for result in find_dirs(entry_path, names, exclude_folders):
                        yield result
    except OSError as e:
        print(e, file=sys.stderr)

product_dirs = []
event_log_path = '/tmp/findlog.txt'
with open(event_log_path, 'a') as log:
    for lib in find_dirs('/', ['lib', 'library'], ['user']):
        print(lib)
        product_dirs.append(lib)
        log.write(lib + "\n")
        break      # Stop after finding the first match
```

Comment: This is great!  It doesn't really answer my original question, but the code could easily be changed to add an elif os.path.isfile()

Answer (score 2):

- Globals are bad. The signature should be

  ```
  def findDir(path, targetNames, exclude = []):
  ```
- Globals are bad. The function should

  ```
  return productDirs
  ```
- Avoid repeated calls. Calculate a qualified path to `directory` once at the beginning of the loop.
- I seriously doubt that printing and logging have any value except debugging. They do not belong to the working code.

Comment: `exclude = []` as a signature is dangerous because it gets constructed at compile time. If you append something to that list, next time you call the function the list would have been modified.